# Conditional extremum with Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

I have the following problem :
Find the extremals of the functional :

[image: Problem]!]

where lampda is Lagrange multipliers
my question is how to solve the differential equation below

sorry L dont =0
[image: Solution]!]

Comment: Can you solve the $y''+y=0$ equation, for example?

Comment: I can't since I don't know the form of "lampda" which is Lagrange-multipliers which is function w.r.t.x